# Using JQuery and JSON to consume Asp.net Server-Side Asynchronous Web Methods

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services, json

I defined two webservices calls in ASP.NET:
 1.BeginLengthyProcedure and EndLengthyProcedure (Asynchronous web method)
 2.LengthProcedureSync

```
namespace ServiceDemo
{
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class AsyncWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public delegate string LengthyProcedureAsyncStub(int milliseconds);

    public string LengthyProcedure(int milliseconds)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
        return "SuccessAsync";
    }

    public class MyState
    {
        public object previousState;
        public LengthyProcedureAsyncStub asyncStub;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public IAsyncResult BeginLengthyProcedure(int milliseconds, AsyncCallback cb, object s)
    {
        LengthyProcedureAsyncStub stub = new LengthyProcedureAsyncStub(LengthyProcedure);
        MyState ms = new MyState();
        ms.previousState = s;
        ms.asyncStub = stub;
        return stub.BeginInvoke(milliseconds, cb, ms);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string EndLengthyProcedure(IAsyncResult call)
    {
        MyState ms = (MyState)call.AsyncState;
        string res = ms.asyncStub.EndInvoke(call);
        return res;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string LengthyProcedureSync(int milliseconds)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
        return "SuccessSync";
    }
}
}
```

Then I consumed them using JQuery, I don't want to use ASP.NET AJAX. LengthProcedureSync worked fine, but LenghtyProcudure didn't work. Is there anything I missed?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function testJson() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //Didn't work
            url: "AsyncWebService.asmx/LengthyProcedure",
            //Work
            //url: "AsyncWebService.asmx/LengthyProcedureSync",
            data: "{'milliseconds':'2000'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#jsonResponse").html(msg.d);
            },
            error: function (msg) {

            }

        });
    };

</script>
```

Comment: Were you able to call BeginLengthyProcedure from jQuery and get results from EndLengthyProcedure? How?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the .NET Framework's ASP.NET AJAX web service handler (which is used for JSON) does not provide support for asynchronous web service calls whereas the default ASP.NET web service handler does. There is an excellent book "Building a Web 2.0 Portal with ASP.NET 3.5" written by Omar AL Zabir describing a workaround for this shortcoming of the ASP.NET AJAX web service handler (see chapter 7, page 177). There is also a sample chapter available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596510503-01-07.aspx). Hope, this helps!

Comment: That's terrible. I hate my job.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
public string LengthyProcedure(int milliseconds)
     {
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
         return "SuccessAsync";
     }
```

to this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string LengthyProcedure(int milliseconds)
     {
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);         
           return "SuccessAsync";
     }
```

Comment: Then I think the client side would call this synchronous web method directly instead of calling the asynchronous web method.

Comment: I think you miss the point, without the decoration, the method will not be exposed as a web method and thus your call to it via url: "AsyncWebService.asmx/LengthyProcedure", is invalid.

Comment: Note as here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  async: defaults to true, but can be set to false if you desire it to be called synchronous

Comment: No, "AsyncWebService.asmx/LengthyProcedure" is valid, it is just an implementation detail, called asynchronous design pattern in .NET. With Begin*** and End*** webmethods, the * method will look and behave exactly as synchronous method. Maybe it is a little bit confusing to use LenghtyProcedure for the first non-webmethod function.